# Color scheme for question page

Tags: feature-request, design

Maybe it's just me, but I find the color scheme for the questions unintuitive. 
I would expect to have the lighter color for questions I have already read and the darker one for unread ones, instead of the other way around as it is now. Darker is more noticable and it would make sense for me to highlight the questions one has not read yet.

Would you agree to this and if yes, is there a possibility of changing it?

For quick reference, here is a screenshot of two questions with the unread one on top:

[image: questions]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All beta sites have the same colour scheme. I think this question has been asked before on meta.se but I don't think there was any appetite to change it.

You can change it yourself, there are user scripts, or simply by editing the CSS.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172821/154443) is a very good answer on how to do this!.

It works for me, but then I see a lot of beta sites so I can't imagine it being any other way.

Comment: Do you have a link to such a user script? All I find searching is people asking how to change some style aspects of their own websites.

Comment: There you go, Helm - edited into the answer. I just did a very quick search of meta.se